Can't find IssuerId in App Store Connect for iOS development in VS2022
I need IssuerId in App Store Connect so I can link Visual Studio 2022 to my iPhone to test cross platform apps.
This is what VS asks for:

Name: (not sure what this is maybe just something I make up?)
IssuerId: (I can't find this)
KeyId: I have this
Private key path: I've downloaded this


VS 2022 has a link when you're pairing your iPhone 'How do I get an API key?' - this links to this documentation page which is now wrong:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/creating_api_keys_for_app_store_connect_api
In lots of other web links it says this should be available in various places that it no longer is.
eg
https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/114567
(in the above link the suggested URL doesn't exist
https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/api)
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/discussions/18926
(in the link above Users and Access / Keys no longer exists)

Does anybody know where I can find this now?
(also any idea what goes in name?)
Thanks
UPDATE
It seems to give me an IssuerID if I create a Team Key rather than an Individual Key.
Anyone know why this is? Can you not connect an iPhone to Visual Studio 2022 with an Individual Key?

Can't tell if this would be it but... I've had a similar error (something about issuerId) on XCode. Turns out, I had to sign in to App Store Connect and accept a new agreement to be able to sign my apps. Take a look in your account and check if you don't have any outstanding agreements to acknowledge.

Yeah good guess I did have to do that too. But I can't even find my Issuer Id anywhere to type into VS. I just need to know where to find that now, it used to be on some App Store Connect pages and now it isn't ‍♂️

Have you tried in https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/integrations/api ? You might have to request access to the API, but if you create a key you should see an issuer ID. I'm not sure if this is the one you need.

This is my Apple account, no other devs are involved so I'm the only person with access (so nobody to request access to etc) and can do what I want. I've created a key in there, I don't see an issuer Id, just a table with 'generated by, keyid, last used, access, apps' ‍♂️

I'm not entirely sure about what keys you need to use in VS, but have you tried creating a Team key? Once you create one you do get an issuer ID.

Thanks yeah that's what I did (update above) - I wonder a) why you only get an issuer id with a team key and b) why VS needs an issuer id? Oh well works anyway thx..

Might be something related to nomenclature, but when you publish an app on your account, you publish it as a 'team' because techncially you could add other users to publish on your behalf. VS needs it to sign the apps, it's mostly a security measure, however the setup is a bit more manual there compared to XCode.
